# Working with both Thread and Task at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, task

As being a newbie with doing threads and tasks, I wrote two threads and one task in my little practice application as below:

> ```
>     static List<string> myList = new List<string>();
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         //Run the whole operation both threads and task.
>         Operation();
>     }
>     static async void Operation()
>     {
>         Task t = Task.Run(new Action(RunThreads));
>         t.Wait();
>
>         //Write the result.
>         WriteMessage();
>     }
>     static void RunThreads()
>     {
>         //Read thread1.
>         string threadName = "Thread-1";
>         Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(threadName));
>         thread1.Name = threadName;
>         thread1.Start();
>
>         //Read thread2.
>         threadName = "Thread-2";
>         Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(threadName));
>         thread2.Name = threadName;
>         thread2.Start();
>     }
>     public static void DoSomething(string threadName)
>     {
>         for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
>         {
>             myList.Add(string.Format("{0} from thread: {1}", i, threadName));
>         }
>     }
>
>     private static void WriteMessage()
>     {
>         foreach (string val in myList)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(val);
>         }
>         Console.Read();
>     }
> ```

I want both threads to be first entirely executed and the values are added in "myList". Once those threads are completed (Eventually by the end of those two threads, "myList" will contain 20 items...) then run the "WriteMessage()" method to loop through all those 20 items and print them in the console.

Below is the output that I am expecting to be written in the console:

- 1 from thread: Thread-2
- 1 from thread: Thread-1
- 2 from thread: Thread-1
- 2 from thread: Thread-2
- 3 from thread: Thread-2
- 4 from thread: Thread-2
- 3 from thread: Thread-1
- 5 from thread: Thread-2
- This list continues upto 20 items.

*(I know that the sequence of messages from "Thread-1" and "Thread-2" may differ because the process will be asynchronous but there should be exactly 10 item for each).*

**The issue with my implementation is:** The WriteMessage() method is being executed before those two threads are completed.

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe!

Comment: You should wait for threads completion. Use `thread1.Join()`, `thread2.Join()` at the end of `RunThreads`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  static object _lock = new object();
        static List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        TaskFactory TaskFac = new TaskFactory();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Run the whole operation both threads and task.
            Operation();
        }
        static async void Operation()
        {
            Task t = Task.Run(new Action(RunThreads)).ContinueWith(o => {

                WriteMessage();


            });
            t.Wait();

            Console.ReadKey();

            //Write the result.
            //  WriteMessage();
        }
        static void RunThreads()
        {
            //Read thread1.
            string threadName = "Thread-1";
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() =>
            {

                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    DoSomething(

                    threadName, i


                    );
                }

            });
            thread1.Start();

            string threadName1 = "Thread-2";
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => { 
             for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                DoSomething(

                threadName1, i


                );
            } });
            thread2.Start();



        }
        public static void DoSomething(string threadName,int loop_index)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            {

                    myList.Add(string.Format("{0} from thread: {1}",loop_index, threadName));

                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }

        }

        private static void WriteMessage()
        {
            foreach (string val in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: In my computer it worked..could you please tell me the error message in the output?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to do is make the `Operation` void wait until the two other threads are completed. What I have done is created a boolean that will turn true when the threads are done, therefore letting the `Operation` continue. This worked for VS2017. On line 2 you can see the bool, line 17 is where it waits, and line 33 is where the boolean is changed. Im currently not on my desktop (laptop, verry slow) so if you are having further problems I can modify this answer.

```
static List<string> myList = new List<string>();

static bool taskDone = false;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Run the whole operation both threads and task.
    Operation();
}
static async void Operation()
{
    Task t = Task.Run(new Action(RunThreads));
    t.Wait();

    //Write the result.
    while(!taskDone);
    WriteMessage();
}
static void RunThreads()
{
    //Read thread1.
    string threadName = "Thread-1";
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(threadName));
    thread1.Name = threadName;
    thread1.Start();

    //Read thread2.
    threadName = "Thread-2";
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => DoSomething(threadName));
    thread2.Name = threadName;
    thread2.Start();

    taskDone = true;
}
public static void DoSomething(string threadName)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myList.Add(string.Format("{0} from thread: {1}", i, threadName));
    }
}

private static void WriteMessage()
{
    foreach (string val in myList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: It still hits the WriteMessage() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task for implementing this. Find the code provided below. Arguments passed to the DoWork function are the parameters to execute the work. This should be dynamically set from the loop for each DoWork call.

```
                int numberOfProcess = 3;
                Task[] _tasks = new Task[numberOfProcess];

                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfProcess; i++)
                {
                    string[] args = new string[2];
                    args[0] = minSlNo.ToString();
                    args[1] = nextSlno.ToString();                     

                    _tasks[i - 1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        //do the required work
                        DoWork(args);
                    });

                    System.Console.WriteLine("Min =" + minSlNo + "  Next Msg=" + nextSlno);
                    SetLogFilesProperty("BatchJob_Start", args[0].ToString() + "_" + args[1].ToString());                    
                }

                while (_tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) 
                {//execution waits till all the tasks are completed  
                }

                Console.Write("All Tasks Completed"+DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: See [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx), [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx).